# C# Построение итераторных методов с использованием ключевого слова yield

Tags: c#, интерфейс

Насколько я понял yield return просто запоминает свое место в методе при следующем вызове этого-же метода. Но:

```
    internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Garage garage = new Garage();
        IEnumerator enumerator = garage.GetEnumerator();

    }
}


    internal class Garage : IEnumerable
{
    public Car[] myCars = new Car[4];
    //Constractors
    public Garage()
    {
        myCars[0] = new Car();
        myCars[1] = new Car();
        myCars[2] = new Car();
        myCars[3] = new Car();

    }

    //Methods
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return myCars[0];
        yield return myCars[1];
        yield return myCars[2];
        yield return myCars[3];
    }
}
```

Каким образом класс Car неявно типизируется в интерфейс "IEnumerator" при возвращении из метода GetEnumerator?? класс Car не наследует никаких интерфейсов! И почему метод срабатывает на вызов MoveNext() интерфейса IEnumerator а не просто при его вызове? битый час пытаюсь понять логику

Comment: Вы используете устаревший необобщенный тип, используйте обобщенный `IEnumerator<Car>`, а так у вас просто идет апкаст к `object`. `Car` никуда не типизируется. `enumerator.Current` это не `IEnumerator`, а именно `Car`. А класс `Garage` вы не показали, не до конца понятно, что здесь где.

Comment: Откуда апкаст к "object" если тут все типы явно приводятся?, и в возвращающем типе из метода "GetEnumerator" и в вызывающем коде.  Я неправильно выразился, типы не меняются, а просто приводятся согласно наследованию (is - a). Но это же ничего не меняет, <bold>тип Car не является IEnumerator</bold> - тогда каким образом метод возвращает тип "Car" неявно приведенный в "IEnumerator" ? Тип garage явно не указан, он наследует интерфейс IENumerable , переопределяет метод GetEnumerator из этого интерфейса, я упустил его чтобы указать только самое главное

Comment: Код целиком покажите

Comment: @aepot средактировал

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "И почему метод срабатывает на вызов MoveNext() интерфейса IEnumerator а не просто при его вызове?". Кто и какой метод кого вызывает вызывает?

Comment: В прошлом ответе я вам показывал как IEnumerator использовать. Не вижу никакого MoveNext в коде и не понимаю, что вы хотите получить. И советовал про конечный автомат почитать. Вы почитали? Судя по вопросу, даже не пытались.

Comment: @aepot Если это решает мой вопрос то конечно почитаю, просто я учусь по книге, и там не объясняется ничего про это. вот ответ на предыдущий ваш вопрос: **   Console.WriteLine((Car)enumerator.Current);**  возвращает null , т.к. не был вызван метод MoveNext()..............

Comment: @aepot вот полный код вызова:  '            Garage garage = new Garage();
            IEnumerator enumerator = garage.GetEnumerator();
            enumerator.MoveNext();
            Console.WriteLine((Car)enumerator.Current);
' В таком случае возвращает первный элемент yeld return

Comment: @aepot код в методе "yield return myCars[0];" возвращает ссылку на объект Car! В свою очередь тип Car не реализует интерфейс IEnumerator! Вопрос - каким боком возвращаемым значением является объект Car который неявно приведен в IEnumerator?

Comment: Никуда он не приведен. IEnumerator.Current здесь возвращает Car. Это ровно тоже самое как Garage.myCars возвращает массив Cars[], вы же не говорите, что Cars[] приведен к Garage, верно? Тогда откуда такие странные вопросы?

Comment: Еще раз, не используйте `IEnumerator`, используйте обобщенный `IEnumerator<T>`. В вашем случае `IEnumerator<Car>`

Comment: @aepot Хорошо, допустим, уберите из метода GetEnumerator() весь код и оставьте только "return myCars[0]" Вот что по моему мнению должно происходить с кодом - Cannot implicitly convert type 'CustomEnumeratorWithYield.Car' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerator'.   Что происходит когда я дописываю yield? Почему ошибки нету?

Comment: Потому что `return` и `yield return` - 2 большие разницы. Вы можете и одно значение оставить, но не убирать `yield`.

Comment: `yield` трансформирует метод в конечный автомат. Дубль 3: почитайте про него.

Comment: @aepot Короче говоря, yield return возвращает IEnumerator типа массива или перечисления (который сам-же и создал)  с единственным объектом **myCars[0];**,  это объясняет почему возвращаемый объект is IEnumerable и IEnumerator. Т.е.  **yield return myCars[0]** == **return new Car[] { myCars[0] }**

Comment: @Alegro вы далеко от того как оно на самом деле. Но если взглянуть на всё извне, то примерно так выглядит, да. Дубль 4: yield делает из метода конечный автомат, никаких массивов он не создает. Путь к пониманию механики лежит через понимание того, как работает конечный автомат.